# Permissions to create Entities in Google Datastore via Cloud Console

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-console

I'm managing a project running in the google cloud and have a team working on it. The team-members are organized in a google group, that has the permission to edit the project. Each team-member can start instances, create container-engine cluster, etc. but it's not possible to create datastore entities.

When I add the team-member directly as editor to the project (not via the google group), he is able to create datastore entities. But I like managing members via the google group, because I can give selected team-members the permission to add team-members without giving them the owner-role of the project.

Is there anything I missed? Or is it just not possible to give project editors added via google group the permission to create entities in the datastore?